# В Safari при рисовании svg Яндекс метки на карте не отображается image часть svg

Tags: svg, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, safari, raphael

Для работы с svg используется RaphaelJs, он создает svg и вставляет его в div, который является placemark на карте.

часть svg, который в итоге получается:

[image]
В итоге на яндекс картах отображается всё, кроме image. Тот же svg на гугл картах отображается полностью. И такая проблема только в Safari, другие браузеры отображают всё.

так выглядит в Яндекс картах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так в гугл картах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так создается метка:

```
var divBya = CreateDivM24Big('ya');
var svgObjBya = CreateSvgM24Big(divBya.div, 'ya');

  var myIconContentLayoutM24Small = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container">' + divBya.div.outerHTML + '</div>', {
    build: function() {
      this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);
    }
  });


  // Создание метки и добавление ее на карту
 var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.752, 37.627], {
    id: 1
  }, {
    draggable: false,
    pixelRendering: 'static',
    pane: 'overlaps',
    iconLayout: myIconContentLayoutM24Small,
    iconShape: {
      type: 'MultiPolygon',
      coordinates: [
        [
          [
            [-120 / 2, -120],
            [120 / 2, -120],
            [120 / 2, 0],
            [-120 / 2, 0]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  });
```

Подробнее пример рисования: https://jsfiddle.net/u2v3jzew/

В хроме и FF работает. В Safari картинка не отображается.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вы предоставите пример, где можно увидеть проблему, это поможет в ней разобраться.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2v3jzew/

Comment: А у RaphaelJs нет побочных эффектов в виде плохой поддержки сафари? Если добавить вот такой костыль https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273775/namespace-prefix-ns1-for-href-on-tagelement-is-not-defined-setattributens , то в сафари начинает работать: https://jsfiddle.net/8u5k6n4q/

Comment: спасибо! самое странное, что только при добавлении svg в метку Яндекса приписывается ns1:href, если точно также строить svg через RaphaelJs вне карты, либо делать меткой Гугл карт, то там нет ns1:href и работает в Safari

Comment: Это баг. Покажите, пожалуйста, код, как вы делали без карт гугл, чтобы в сафари работало. У меня так не получается https://jsfiddle.net/uwjmhyep/

Comment: https://www.mingli.ru/24mountain#builtYear=2019&DegreeGuid=348.960&AngleMySVG=11.04&Lat=60.03507&Lng=30.41198&CSYear=2018&CSMonth=4&zoom=8&ShowGMap=true&FSMap=true&USEDeclBYear=true&Map=JaMap&ShType=0 например, по этой ссылке отображается картинка, тут svg накладывается сверху на карту, просто слоем div, не привязываясь к маркеру

Comment: ну это не совсем минимальный пример которого я ждал, тяжело там будет найти концы к сожалению. Я подготовил минимальный пример без яндекс карт и он не работает в сафари https://jsfiddle.net/uwjmhyep/